# How to Add Image Scaling and Positioning Behind Mask Layer for Preview Application

Tags: java, c++

I am trying to build a website for printing a user-uploaded image on custom cell phone cases, and have found a built-in feature for wix that has every feature I need except for the ability to scale and position the image. Currently, it uploads the image and is stuck in that static position, and doesn't let the user position it, so the image is randomly cropped. I have some experience with Python and HTML, but I do not even known where to start with this code. If this is a simple feature to add, would anyone mind throwing a solution out there? I believe in the "teach a man to fish" philosophy, but in this instance we don't have time for that. Including the open source code from Wix and a screen shot of what the feature looks like now. Any help is much appreciated!

```
export function addToCartBtn_click(event, $w) {
    // Get the current product.
    const currentProduct = 
$w('#dynamicDataset').getCurrentItem().product;
    // Add the current product to the cart with the user's chosen 
background color, text color, custom text, and custom background 
image.
    $w('#shoppingCartIcon1').addToCart(currentProduct._id, 1, {
        "choices": {
            "Background Color": $w('#colorText').text,
            "Text Color": $w('#textColorName').text
        },
```

I have narrowed it down to this function, which I am pretty sure is where the additional code would need to go, but that is as far as I have been able to get.

````
//-------------Global Variables-------------//

// A static list of random phrases to be used when a user clicks the random button.
var randomPhrases = [
   "You're my definition of perfect.",
   "You keep me safe, I'll keep you wild.",
   "You're the macaroni to my cheese.",
   "I pinky promise I will love you forever.",
   "Stay Safe. Eat Cake.",
   "Veni, Vidi, Vici."
];

//-------------Data Setup-------------//

// Set up the background color and text color repeaters when the dataset has finished loading. 
export function dynamicDataset_ready() {
   // Get the product data from the current item.
   const currentProduct = $w("#dynamicDataset").getCurrentItem().product;
   // Get the product options from the product data.
   const productOptions = currentProduct.productOptions;
   // Set the background color repeater with the choices from the product's Background Color option. 
   $w('#bgColorRepeater').data = createColorRepeaterData('bgcolor', productOptions['Background Color'].choices);
   // Set the text color repeater with the choices from the product's Text Color option. 
   $w('#textColorRepeater').data = createColorRepeaterData('textcolor', productOptions['Text Color'].choices);
}

// Add an ID to the choices data so it can be used to populate a repeater.
function createColorRepeaterData(idPrefix, choices) {
   // Use the JavaScript map() function to add an _id field to each data item.
   return choices.map((item, index) => {
       item._id = `${idPrefix}-${index}`;
       return item;
   });
}

//-------------Repeater Setup-------------//

// Set up each item in the background colors repeater as it is loaded.
// Each item has a box that contains its color and a transparent button layered on top of the box. 
export function bgColorRepeater_itemReady($w, itemData, index) {
   // Set the current box's color to be the color from the current item's data.
   $w('#bgColorBox').style.backgroundColor = itemData.value;
   // Set the action that occurs when a user clicks the current background color button.
   $w('#bgColorBtn').onClick(() => {
       // Call the updateBackgroudColor() function with the current item's data.
       updateBackgroundColor(itemData);
   });
}

// Set up each item in the text colors repeater as it is loaded.
// Each item has a box that contains its color and a transparent button layered on top of the box.
export function textColorRepeater_itemReady($w, itemData, index) {
   // Set the current box's color to be the color from the current item's data.
   $w('#textColorBox').style.backgroundColor = itemData.value;
   // Set the action that occurs when a user clicks on a text color button.
   $w('#textColorBtn').onClick(() => {
       // Call the updateTextColor() function with the current item's data.
       updateTextColor(itemData);
   });
}

// Update the background color of the product image.
// There is a transparent product image mask layered on top of a box that changes colors. 
function updateBackgroundColor(colorItem) {
   // Set the text label in the color chooser to be the specified color.
   $w('#colorText').text = colorItem.description;
   // Set the background color of the box behind the transparent product image.
   $w("#bgColor").style.backgroundColor = colorItem.value;
}

// Update the color of the custom text.
function updateTextColor(colorItem) {
   // Set the text label in the color chooser to be the specified color.
   $w('#textColorName').text = colorItem.description;
   // Retrieve the value of the custom text and reset its color using inline html styling.
   $w("#customText").html = "<h6 style='text-align:center;color:" + colorItem.value + "'>" + $w('#customText').text + "</h6>";
}

//-------------Element Event Handlers-------------//

// Change the customization options when a user clicks the Custom Text "tab". 
export function tabMenuText_click(event, $w) {
   $w("#textBox").show();
   $w("#bgBox").hide();
   $w("#tabMenuText").disable();
   $w("#tabMenuBg").enable();
}

// Change the customization options when a user clicks the Background "tab". 
export function tabMenuBg_click(event, $w) {
   $w("#bgBox").show();
   $w("#textBox").hide();
   $w("#tabMenuText").enable();
   $w("#tabMenuBg").disable();
}

// Update the custom text layer on top of the product image when information is entered in the text input element.
export function textInput_keyPress(event, $w) {
   // Delay updating for a tenth of a second to smooth out updates.
   setTimeout(() => {
       // Get the value from the custom text input element.
       const textToShow = $w("#textInput").value;
       // Set the value of the custom text layer on top of the product image.
       $w('#customText').text = textToShow;
       // If there is custom text:
       if (textToShow) {
           // Show the custom text layer.
           $w('#customText').show();
       } else {
           // Otherwise, hide the custom text layer.
           $w('#customText').hide();
       }
   }, 10);
}

// Set a random custom text when the random button is clicked.
export function randomButton_click(event, $w) {
   // Choose a random index value.
   const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomPhrases.length);
   // Set the custom text on the product image to the chosen random text.
   $w('#customText').text = randomPhrases[randomIndex];
   // Set the custom text in the custom text input element to the chosen random text.
   $w('#textInput').value = randomPhrases[randomIndex];
   // Show the custom text layer on the product image.
   $w('#customText').show();
}

// Automatically start the upload of the selected file 1 second after it is chosen.
export function uploadButton_change(event, $w) {
   // If there is a chosen file:
   if ($w("#uploadButton").value.length > 0) {
       //Automatically start the upload of the file 1 second after it is chosen.
       setTimeout(() => {
           $w("#uploadButton").startUpload().then(uploadedFile => {
               $w("#print").src = uploadedFile.url;
           });
       }, 1000);
   }
}

// Add the customized item to the shopping cart.
export function addToCartBtn_click(event, $w) {
   // Get the current product.
   const currentProduct = $w('#dynamicDataset').getCurrentItem().product;
   // Add the current product to the cart with the user's chosen background color, text color, custom text, and custom background image.
   $w('#shoppingCartIcon1').addToCart(currentProduct._id, 1, {
       "choices": {
           "Background Color": $w('#colorText').text,
           "Text Color": $w('#textColorName').text
       },
       "customTextFields": [{
               "title": "Custom Text",
               "value": $w('#textInput').value
           },
           {
               "title": "Background Image",
               "value": $w('#print').src
           }
       ]
   });
}

function updateMenuButtons() {
   $w('#repeater1').forEachItem(($w, itemData) => {
       const currentDynamicId = $w('#dynamicDataset').getCurrentItem()._id;
       if (currentDynamicId === itemData._id) {
           $w('#button1').disable();
       } else {
           $w('#button1').enable();
       }
   });
}

export function dataset1_ready() {
   updateMenuButtons()
}```
````

Comment: Is the C++ language tag a mistake?

Comment: Honestly I really don't know what it is written in. Thought it looked similar to C++ but really only a little familiar with HTML and Python

Comment: The code you've posted is not C++.